# XXX doesn't contain a definition and no extension method

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to access some methods and properties of a third party unmanaged DLL from my VS2010 C# project.  One property in particular “disappears” when trying to access it after I added the DLL to the reference.   I am using MS VS2010 and the target platform is an XP SP3 x86.

From the .NET VB, the Item property is shown as

```
Item([Object], [Object]) As Object
```

or

```
ReadOnly Default Property Item(Optional ByVal Name As Object = Nothing, Optional ByVal Index As Object = Nothing) As Object
```

I can use it with no problem.
However, in C#, this property disappears and the closest one I can find become

```
this[[object], [object]]
```

or

```
dynamic this[[object Name = System.Type.Missing], [object Index = System.Type.Missing]] { get; }
```

How do I access this property in my C# project?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Item property in VB.NET is the indexer in C#.
So, the following VB.NET and C# codes are equivalent:

```
/* VB.NET */
yourObject.Item(o1, o2)

/* C# */
yourObject[o1, o2];
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) and can be accessed like this.

```
var yourObj = new SomeObject();
var item = yourObj[value1,value2];
```

In other words you just use `[]` brackets after the object variable itself, rather than `Item()`